# Can "progeny" take the plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number

> There were things his grandchildren, in turn, should know. Yet he hesitated. How do you tell your children they are *progenies* of the self-proclaimed inventor of Manhattan clam chowder? (The New York Times)

Oxford Dictionaries say "progeny" is a noun
treated as singular or plural, but on Internet I found a number of occurrences of "progenies" and, hence, a doubt arose to my mind: is it entirely wrong pluralize "progeny"?

Comment: "they are progeny" vs "they are progenies" - the latter garners more hits on Ngram than the former, although both are very thin. It appears that when the focus is on the progeny and not the progenitor, *progenies* tends to be used. "However, the Sinhalese dispute it and think that they are the original inhabitants of Sri Lanka and they are progenies of a North lndian King Vijaya, who had migrated to Ceylon about 2500 years ago."[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=LvUeAAAAMAAJ&q=%22they+are+progenies%22&dq=%22they+are+progenies%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS6c_-t_DhAhVDSK0KHUsSCv4Q6AEIMjAC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that your citation sounds strange; at least, it does to my ear. Reading that I almost wonder whether the author hasn’t somehow conflated *progeny* and *prodigy*, since the latter’s plural form is unremarkable.

However, digging deeper, one finds that the [OED entry for *progeny*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/152178), last updated in 2007, makes no mention one way or the other.  It gives as its sense 1a

> **1a**. Offspring, issue, children; descendants. *Occas*.: a child, a descendant; a family.

a definition that is already in the plural, but which admits a singular sense “occasionally”.  Sense **1b** is more figurative:

> **1b**. *fig.* Spiritual, intellectual, or artistic descendants; successors; followers, disciples.

And is still plural, and gives this citation of *progeny* itself taking plural concordance:

> - 1994   H. Bloom *Western Canon* ii. iii. 80  
>    Dante’s progeny among the writers are his true canonizers.

However, down under sense 1d:

> **1d**. The product of the breeding of animals or plants; the offspring of sexual or asexual reproduction. Now chiefly *Agric*. and *Genetics*.

We find that there is indeed an inflected plural version — *progenies* — given as an example:

> - 1977   *Crop Sci*. 17 909/2  
>    Twenty-one clones whose polycross progenies ranked high for rate of seedling emergence under field conditions or had high forage yield..were selected for this study.

So it appears that when dealing with people, *progeny* is taken as a plural with some use as a singular, but when used in a genetic sense, it can occasionally be taken as a count noun that inflects regularly.

Comment: Surely the point is that a person (or plant) has *progeny* (not a progeny) no matter how many children that may be, and only geneticists would have occasion to consider a possible plural. I would say that is borderline jargon; it is certainly not the NYT usage.

Comment: @TimLymington You may be right. The NYT usage sound really wrong to me.

Comment: I'm up for this one. But I think the short answer is just that *progeny* functions much the same as *offspring* (or indeed, *fish*). Grammatically there's no reason why they shouldn't be pluralised in the normal way - but since the "singular" forms are well-established as valid plurals anyway, there's no need to. So for the most part, we just don't.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The only OED citation that uses *a progeny* with a leading indefinite article like that is from before 1439, so can hardly represent modern usage in support of the word as a count noun. It came to us by way of Anglo-Norman and Middle French *progenie* without an *-s*, but that in turn derived from Latin *prōgeniēs* which had one and where *-iēs* was just the suffix for forming agent nouns, not a plural. There is some confusion in English about the number of *-ies* nouns (*series*, *species*, but *in specie* from the ablative), so it’s probably just as well we lost that *-s*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OED example from 1947 seems to settle it for me. If Adam's "progeny" is not pluralised, then it can only be a non-count noun. *1947   M. E. Boylan This Tremendous Lover (new ed.) ii. 15   If Adam had not sinned, original sin would not have been transmitted to his progeny.*

Comment: My reading of the 1977 Crop Sci. 17 909/2 quote is that the distinction is being made between the progeny (however many) of one plant and the progenies of many plants. The progenies form is being used to distinguish multiple collections of progeny from a single collections of progeny. This seems to fit with a couple of the other search results I get when looking up "progeny vs progenies"

Answer (score 2):

[Dictionaries differ](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/progenies) in the plural of *progeny.* Most list *progeny* as a plural, although [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/progeny) does not. All list *progenies* as a plural, although Oxford and Random House use this form only for animals and plants, not children.

Comment: OED does not recognize *progenies* at all, and neither would I.

Comment: I suspect that _progenies_ is an American usage. I noted the Oxford exception to "all," thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @TimLymington But the OED actually has a citation that uses *progenies*, as I show in my answer.  Still, it is very bizarre.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, good catch. I refined my edit to reflect it. _Progenies_ sounds wrong to me too, so I'm not sure whether it's actually legit American English, or whether the other American dictionaries are just being sloppy about usage notes. If you can resolve that, your excellent answer will totally supersede mine, and I'll delete this one. (And it's not all that unusual to make language distinctions between husbandry and children; some people distinguish between _raise_ for husbandry and _rear_ for children.)

Comment: It does not sound legit to my ear, either. So either the NYT is become the domain of jargony geneticists, or it’s lost its editors.  Or both.

Comment: @tchrist Logic would suggest that whilst a single subject only has one progeny (however many individuals that may amount to), multiple subjects would have their separate "progenies". Hence twenty-one clones have twenty-one progenies. Even non-count nouns form plurals in this way e.g. "the separate *waters* of the Mediterranean and the Red Sea are connected by the Suez canal".

Comment: @WS2 Compare with *one offspring*. The thing about mass nouns is that because you cannot them, it feels wrong to talk about one of them: prefixing them with any number at all, including that number *one*, belies their nature as uncountable. With your *one progeny*, it isn't quite so weird as saying one clothes or one happiness or one air or one cattle or one east or one aging, but the creative native speaker might be able.to construct plausible reference frames for most of those, too. .

Comment: Is *offspring* a mass noun? Is it not simply a count-noun without a separate plural - like *sheep*? But *progeny* (like *posterity*) seems to me to be a mass noun. Though if there are separate subjects, there must arise plurals. You, I and Alexander the Great, each have a progeny - but together we have progenies.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the word 'progeny' is children which is a plural word hence it is a plural word and can be used with both singular and plural verbs according to the sense it makes in the sentence.