# What is the correct plural form of "offspring"?

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the correct plural form of the word "offspring"?

From the dictionaries I have looked at, I am guessing it is just "offspring", but Dictionary.com and Merriam-Webster say "offsprings" is also acceptable.

> **offspring** *noun* (plural **offspring**, **offsprings**)

*Dictionary.com*

> **offspring** *noun* (plural **offspring**, **offsprings**)

*Merriam-Webster*

> **offspring** *noun* (plural **offspring**)

*Cambridge Dictionaries Online*

> **offspring** *noun* (plural **offspring**)

*Oxford Dictionaries*

Macquarie Dictionary and OED have no mention of the plural form.

The sentence I want to use the word in is:

> ...more long-legged frogs exist to generate long-legged [offspring(s)].

In this context "offspring" as a plural (without the "S") doesn't sound right.

Comment: Related: [Can 'progeny' take the plural form?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/111957/8019).

Comment: Funny, to me it only  sounds right without the ’s’.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Google Books Ngram Viewer, **Offspring** is more common, in the past 200 years, so the negligible usage of **Offsprings** might be attributed to a few ignorant authors.

**Very common usage of Offspring vs negligible usage of Offsprings**
[image: Very common usage of Offspring vs negligible usage of Offsprings]

**Very common usage of Fish vs smaller (but not negligible) usage of fishes**
[image: Very common usage of Fish vs smaller (but not negligible) usage of fishes]

**Possible Explanation:**
**Fish** and **Fishes** are both correct, but the singular is generally more common, and the ratio looks good. So we can consider that both are used normally.
**Offspring** is correct and is used commonly, while **Offspings**, being "wrong" in some sense, has negligible usage, and the ratio is "abnormally low". So we can consider that Offsprings should be avoided?

Comment: How do you differentiate between the use of "offspring" in the singular from the plural? Obviously, as with "fish", the far more common use of the word is in the singular, and this is what the Ngram Viewer is showing you.

Comment: @dotancohen That's a really good point. The thought hadn't even crossed my mind.

Comment: @dotancohen , hope my edit answers your question.

Comment: The plurial of "fish" depends on whether you are talking about several individuals of the same species or several species of fish. "Fishes" is used when we are referring to several species of fish. Example coming from  [here](http://tellmewhyfacts.com/2007/01/when-do-you-use-word-fish-and-fishes.html) and [there](http://crofsblogs.typepad.com/english/2005/02/fish_or_fishes.html): *There are a lot fishes in the sea.* or *The fishes of the Fraser River include salmon and sturgeon*

Comment: @Remi.b: That's an over-simplification. "[If wishes were fishes...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186771/what-does-if-wishes-were-fishes-wed-all-swim-in-riches-mean)" doesn't mean "If wishes were different fish species."

Answer (score 2):

> From the 16c. to the early 19c. a **plural form** **offsprings** was
>   current but since then this **ancient word** (found already in OE) has
>   been **invariable in form** (*[Fowler's Modern English Usage](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en-IN&source=hp&q=fowler%27s%20modern%20english%20usage%20latest%20edition&gbv=2&oq=Fowler%27s%20Modern%20English%20Usage&gs_l=heirloom-hp.1.2.0j0i20j0l5j0i20j0l2.1202.4634.0.10265.4.4.0.0.0.0.468.468.4-1.1.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..3.1.468.vXgw7s6pBrI)*).

USAGE EXAMPLES :

> - The widows and the **offsprings** of the poorer, the indigent clergy (1756)
> - These **are** the **offspring** of Muslim parents; the son tried to become    the worthy offspring of his famous father.
> - Better to start when the offspring **are** young and will have no solid memories of particularly rough times.(Washington Times, May 27,
>     2015)
> - The Norway rat has a three-week gestation period and can produce five    litters a year, each with four to eight **offspring**. (The
>     Verge,May 13,    2015)

Answer (score 0):

I just Googled around and found that some of the other references like
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/offsprings
Or
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offspring
Or
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/offspring

All of the above supports the plural form **offsprings**.

Even in medical or biological contex, **offsprings** is used as a plural of **offspring**.    (As per the American Heritage® Stedman's Medical Dictionary)

However, the use of **Offsprings** is too less.

Answer (score -1):

One modern example of the use of "offsprings" is in the 2016 edition of the English Standard Version (ESV) of the Bible in Galatians 3:16:

16 Now the promises were made to Abraham and to his offspring. It does not say, “And to offsprings,” referring to many, but referring to one, “And to your offspring,” who is Christ.

The intent here is to emphasize the difference between the singular and the plural.